# what wrong with cloudinary.uploader.upload python?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload files from Django back-end to cloudinary using cloudinary.uploader.upload() method. As file to upload i use local file 'pic.jpg' `cloudinary.uploader.upload('pic.jpg')
cloudinary.uploader.upload(open('pic.jpg', 'r'))`, link 'example.com/img/pic.jpg' `cloudinary.uploader.upload('example.com/img/pic.jpg')` and Base64 image `cloudinary.uploader.upload('data:image/png;base64,iV...II=')`. For all calls for method i was getting 'TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object'
What wrong with cloudinary.uploader.upload()? (or with me?)

P.S. sorry for my English :(

P.S.S python 3.4 and cloudinary lib 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix was just deployed for better compatibility to Python3.
Please upgrade to Cloudinary version 1.3.1 and see if it solves your issue as well.